# How to compute the lag operator denominator in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am learning the transfer function model in time series and I want to replicate the example in a 1977 paper [here](http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/articles/5004484/exposition-box-jenkins-transfer-function-analysis-application-advertising-sales-relationship) with the Pinkham data in R. However, I'm stuck at the step of identifying the noise process. In my understanding, after obtaining the estimation of the transfer function [image], I need to calculate the residuals [image] and check its autocorrelation.

Now, I have the estimated transfer function as [image], and I know [image]. How to actually code it and compute [image] in R? In other words, how to implement the lag operator polynomial when it's the denominator? My current code is based on the equation that [image]:

```
sum_x = rep(0, length(x))
for (i in 0:(length(x)-1)){
    sum_x = sum_x + delta_1^i * lag(x, -i, na.pad=TRUE)  
}
n = y - w_0 * sum_x
```

Could anyone tell me if this is the correct way to compute the lag operator polynomial?

Even if the above is correct, I'm not sure how to extend the case to other form of polynomials such as [image] in the denomimator. Perhaps some approximation tricks can be applied?

I'm new to time series analysis and any pointer (theories, tools) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!